# How to split a window multiple times in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Oracle JDeveloper I can split a window 10 or 20 times if I want.

How do I do this in Eclipse ?

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Since only single split per editor is possible (at least out-of-the-box; maybe there is a plugin for that), you have to work with multiple editors for the same content by using _Window > Editor > Clone_.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the Emacs+ plugin, which doesn't require any particular experience with or understanding of Emacs.  It simply adds additional capabilities.

With Emacs+, the "split-window-vertically" function splits the current window, whether that window was itself split from the initial window or not.  You can split windows an arbitrary number of times.

You also have "split-window-horizontally", which does what you think.

Going back, there is also "join-other-windows" and "deactivate-window".  The latter removes the current window, and the former removes all the other windows.

There is also "other-window", to move the focus to the next window.

All of these can be bound to keystrokes.  I don't touch the mouse very often.

You can install Emacs+ from the marketplace.

https://sites.google.com/a/mulgasoft.com/www/

https://groups.google.com/g/emacsplus